# yii2 unit test doesnt add records in db

Tags: php, yii2, codeception, phpunit

Help me please to understand how unit tests work in Yii2. I wrote tests:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\tests\unit\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\Category;

class ContactFormTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    public function testAddCorrect()
    {
        $model = new Category();

        $model->attributes = [
            'name' => 'Tester',
            'cpu' => 'new-tester',
            'description' => 'very important letter subject',
            'image' => 'body of current message',
        ];
        $this->assertTrue($model->save());



        $this->assertTrue($model->name === 'Tester');
        $id = $model->id;

        $newmodel = Category::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one(); 
        $this->assertTrue($newmodel->name === 'Tester');

    }
```

And i was expected it adds new record in data base. But it doesn't. Tests woks well but noting adds in db.I can't understand why? And with way i have to write test that will check model + db?

unit.suit.yml

```
suite_namespace: frontend\tests\unit
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, email, fixtures]
        - Asserts
        - Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=docker.for.mac.localhost;dbname=store-light'
            user: 'ysk_dbu'
            password: 'ysk_pass'
            cleanup: false
            #            cleanup: true
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have enabled `transaction` mode? See https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2

Comment: Can you post the contents of unit.suite.yml?

Comment: I add unit.suite.yml in the first message.